# Infinite Loop Based On State in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, loops, react-redux

I would like to toggle infinite loop inside my React component with Redux state. This is what I've got until now but it does not work correctly because it does not stop when the state is changed because the function uses the old version of it.

```
const { monitors } = useSelector((state) => state.monitors)

useEffect(() => {
    handleMonitoring(monitors)
}, [monitors])

const handleMonitoring = async () => {
    if (monitors && monitors.filter(monitor => { return monitor.active }).length) {
        await dispatch(watchMonitors(monitors));
        return handleMonitoring()
    }
    else {
        console.log('closed')
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why? Why do you need call that in an infinite loop? Why not just calling `handleMonitoring` function?

Comment: In the infinite loop I am requesting an api and wait until it is updated, that is why I would need to call that function every few seconds. Do you maybe have any better ideas on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must declare an additional variable to determine if you want to continue the monitoring.

This variable will be initialized to `true` and set to `false` in the cleanup function.

```
const { monitors } = useSelector(state => state.monitors)

useEffect(() => {
    let active = true;
    
    async function handleMonitoring() {
      while(active && monitors && monitors.find(m => m.active)) {
        await dispatch(watchMonitors(monitors));
      }
      console.log('closed');
    }

    handleMonitoring();

    return () => { active = false; };
}, [monitors]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using a recursive function instead of an infinite loop is better idea.

```
const handleMonitoring = async () => {
  await dispatch(watchMonitors(monitors));
  if(monitors && monitors.filter(monitor => { return monitor.active }).length) {
    return;
  }
  else {
    return handleMonitoring()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Should I call this function inside useEffect with empty brackets [ ] ?

Comment: Yeah. call this at the first of component! inside that useEffect with empty dep ( [] ). @nevo_e

Comment: Does it help? @nevo_e

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I tried it but it still does not work. Firstly, I changed it so it returns the function when if statement is true. Secondly, the function does not stop calling it self after the redux state is changed. I confirmed it that it does update correctly and it is how it should be, just the function uses the old version of redux state. Any suggestions?

Comment: Also I am calling the function for the first time inside useEffect with [monitors] dep so it is not calling it only once when the component is mounted.

Comment: Can you provide a codepen or sth else? @nevo_e